# What is the [sending] tag for?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

What is the [sending](/questions/tagged/sending) tag for? Those 108 questions about be re-labelled and the `sending` tag blacklisted in some way, methinks.

Comment: Hey, at least it's got one follower. That's more than `[receiving]` has...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed - looks like the most common use was folks typing "sending email" into the tags box.

[image: Burninated]

Comment: I think it's time for a new trogdor logo, He's not HD in all his majesty as he could be :(. I'll try some Chiaroscuro shading. Just don't BMW lighter me!